# Is there a way to replace mapping values with another variables value in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have following mapping defined

```
def e_environments = [["demo1@mystuff.com":"file1"], ["demo2@mystuff.com":"file1"], ["insurance1@mystuff.com":"file2"], ["insurance2@mystuff.com":"file2"]]
```

Is there a way to replace URL's with same file name from a variable value. For example

```
def demo_env = ["demo1@mystuff.com","demo2@mystuff.com"]
def insurance_env= ["insurance1@mystuff.com","insurance2@mystuff.com"]
def def e_environments = [[${demo_env}:"file1"], [${insurance_env}:"file2"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must have made some efforts from your side before asking here. 
Here is something for you to work upon,

```
def e_environments = [ "demo1@mystuff.com":"file1", "demo2@mystuff.com":"file1" ,  "insurance1@mystuff.com":"file2" ,"insurance2@mystuff.com":"file2" ]
def temp = []
e_environments.keySet().each{
  temp.add(e_environments[it])
}
temp.unique().each{ val ->  
  println e_environments.findAll{it.value==val}
}
```

1. Got all keys from Map
2. Created a unique list of it
3. And a little bit of groovy magic for you to fix and figure it out.